# Wrong extent when importing geotiff into R

Tags: raster, r, digital-image-processing, worldview-2

I am trying to import a geotiff of 8-band satellite imagery into R using raster.

g <- raster('16SEP22191919-M1BS-057310833010_01_P001.tif' )

When I call the object it displays the extent as the the image size in pixels despite having the correct CRS info (I think):

> g
>   class       : RasterLayer
>   band        : 1  (of  8  bands)
>   dimensions  : 4336, 10651, 46182736  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
>   resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
>   extent      : 0, 10651, 0, 4336  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>   coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
>   data source : D:\Digital Globe   Imagery\nasongeotiff\057310833010_01_003\057310833010_01\057310833010_01_P001_MUL\16SEP22191919-M1BS-057310833010_01_P001.tif
>   names       : X16SEP22191919.M1BS.057310833010_01_P001
>   values      : 0, 65535  (min, max)

If I try to display the image I get this error:

> plotRGB(g, r = 5, g = 3, b = 2, axes = TRUE, stretch = "lin")
>   Warning message:
>   In couldBeLonLat(x) :
>     raster has a longitude/latitude CRS, but coordinates do not match that

This file correctly imports into in ArcMap with the appropriate coordinates, and has this info:

- GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG",4326]]

The correct lat and long extents should be (-120.893178348, -120.703696534, 47.7366916019, 47.797656863), but i have had no luck defining the extent in R. Unfortunately the file is way too large (>1gb) for me to post.

Edit: There is an associated .imd file. Here are its contents: 
    version = "28.3";
    generationTime = 2017-12-06T20:55:20.000000Z;
    productOrderId = "057310833010_01_P001";
    productCatalogId = "A010010322340E00";
childCatalogId = "2020010322340F00";
imageDescriptor = "Basic1B";
bandId = "Multi";
panSharpenAlgorithm = "None";
numRows = 4336; 
numColumns = 10651; 
productLevel = "LV1B";
productType = "Basic";
numberOfLooks = 1;
radiometricLevel = "Corrected"; 
bitsPerPixel = 16;
compressionType = "None";
BEGIN_GROUP = BAND_C
    ULLon = -120.89338929;
    ULLat =   47.79786951;
    ULHAE =  1241.94;
    URLon = -120.70434797;
    URLat =   47.79312915;
    URHAE =   648.78;
    LRLon = -120.70392538;
    LRLat =   47.73691772;
    LRHAE =   989.68;
    LLLon = -120.89205130;
    LLLat =   47.74075361;
    LLHAE =  1813.30;
    absCalFactor = 1.432870e-02;
    effectiveBandwidth = 4.050000e-02;
    TDILevel = 24;
END_GROUP = BAND_C
BEGIN_GROUP = BAND_B
    ULLon = -120.89338929;
    ULLat =   47.79786951;
    ULHAE =  1241.94;
    URLon = -120.70434797;
    URLat =   47.79312915;
    URHAE =   648.78;
    LRLon = -120.70392538;
    LRLat =   47.73691772;
    LRHAE =   989.68;
    LLLon = -120.89205130;
    LLLat =   47.74075361;
    LLHAE =  1813.30;
    absCalFactor = 1.160760e-02;
    effectiveBandwidth = 5.400000e-02;
    TDILevel = 21;
END_GROUP = BAND_B
BEGIN_GROUP = BAND_G
    ULLon = -120.89338929;
    ULLat =   47.79786951;
    ULHAE =  1241.94;
    URLon = -120.70434797;
    URLat =   47.79312915;
    URHAE =   648.78;
    LRLon = -120.70392538;
    LRLat =   47.73691772;
    LRHAE =   989.68;
    LLLon = -120.89205130;
    LLLat =   47.74075361;
    LLHAE =  1813.30;
    absCalFactor = 8.856680e-03;
    effectiveBandwidth = 6.180000e-02;
    TDILevel = 21;
END_GROUP = BAND_G
BEGIN_GROUP = BAND_Y
    ULLon = -120.89338929;
    ULLat =   47.79786951;
    ULHAE =  1241.94;
    URLon = -120.70434797;
    URLat =   47.79312915;
    URHAE =   648.78;
    LRLon = -120.70392538;
    LRLat =   47.73691772;
    LRHAE =   989.68;
    LLLon = -120.89205130;
    LLLat =   47.74075361;
    LLHAE =  1813.30;
    absCalFactor = 6.843070e-03;
    effectiveBandwidth = 3.810000e-02;
    TDILevel = 24;
END_GROUP = BAND_Y
BEGIN_GROUP = BAND_R
    ULLon = -120.89338929;
    ULLat =   47.79786951;
    ULHAE =  1241.94;
    URLon = -120.70434797;
    URLat =   47.79312915;
    URHAE =   648.78;
    LRLon = -120.70392538;
    LRLat =   47.73691772;
    LRHAE =   989.68;
    LLLon = -120.89205130;
    LLLat =   47.74075361;
    LLHAE =  1813.30;
    absCalFactor = 1.020000e-02;
    effectiveBandwidth = 5.850000e-02;
    TDILevel = 14;
END_GROUP = BAND_R
BEGIN_GROUP = BAND_RE
    ULLon = -120.89338929;
    ULLat =   47.79786951;
    ULHAE =  1241.94;
    URLon = -120.70434797;
    URLat =   47.79312915;
    URHAE =   648.78;
    LRLon = -120.70392538;
    LRLat =   47.73691772;
    LRHAE =   989.68;
    LLLon = -120.89205130;
    LLLat =   47.74075361;
    LLHAE =  1813.30;
    absCalFactor = 6.219960e-03;
    effectiveBandwidth = 3.870000e-02;
    TDILevel = 24;
END_GROUP = BAND_RE 
BEGIN_GROUP = BAND_N
    ULLon = -120.89338929;
    ULLat =   47.79786951;
    ULHAE =  1241.94;
    URLon = -120.70434797;
    URLat =   47.79312915;
    URHAE =   648.78;
    LRLon = -120.70392538;
    LRLat =   47.73691772;
    LRHAE =   989.68;
    LLLon = -120.89205130;
    LLLat =   47.74075361;
    LLHAE =  1813.30;
    absCalFactor = 1.179710e-02;
    effectiveBandwidth = 1.004000e-01;
    TDILevel = 14;
END_GROUP = BAND_N
BEGIN_GROUP = BAND_N2
    ULLon = -120.89338929;
    ULLat =   47.79786951;
    ULHAE =  1241.94;
    URLon = -120.70434797;
    URLat =   47.79312915;
    URHAE =   648.78;
    LRLon = -120.70392538;
    LRLat =   47.73691772;
    LRHAE =   989.68;
    LLLon = -120.89205130;
    LLLat =   47.74075361;
    LLHAE =  1813.30;
    absCalFactor = 1.063780e-02;
    effectiveBandwidth = 8.890000e-02;
    TDILevel = 24;
END_GROUP = BAND_N2 
outputFormat = "GeoTIFF";
BEGIN_GROUP = IMAGE_1
    satId = "WV03";
    mode = "FullSwath";
    scanDirection = "Forward";
    CatId = "1040010021D24C00";
    TLCTime = 2016-09-22T19:19:19.004450Z;
    numTLC = 2;
    TLCList = (
    (0,  0.000000),
    (4336,  0.867200)
    firstLineTime = 2016-09-22T19:19:19.004450Z;
    avgLineRate = 5000.00;
    exposureDuration = 0.00020000;
    minCollectedRowGSD =   1.414;
    maxCollectedRowGSD =   1.415;
    meanCollectedRowGSD =   1.414;
    minCollectedColGSD =   1.345;
    maxCollectedColGSD =   1.346;
    meanCollectedColGSD =   1.346;
    meanCollectedGSD =   1.380;
    meanProductRowGSD =   1.415;
    meanProductColGSD =   1.341;
    meanProductGSD =   1.378;
    rowUncertainty =   29.99;
    colUncertainty =   11.97;
    minSunAz = 167.8;
    maxSunAz = 167.8;
    meanSunAz = 167.8;
    minSunEl =  41.7;
    maxSunEl =  41.7;
    meanSunEl =  41.7;
    minSatAz = 159.0;
    maxSatAz = 159.8;
    meanSatAz = 159.5;
    minSatEl =  67.9;
    maxSatEl =  68.4;
    meanSatEl =  68.1;
    minInTrackViewAngle = -16.7;
    maxInTrackViewAngle = -16.7;
    meanInTrackViewAngle = -16.7;
    minCrossTrackViewAngle =  10.5;
    maxCrossTrackViewAngle =  10.6;
    meanCrossTrackViewAngle =  10.5;
    minOffNadirViewAngle =  19.6;
    maxOffNadirViewAngle =  19.7;
    meanOffNadirViewAngle =  19.7;
    PNIIRS = 3.5;
    cloudCover = 0.003;
    resamplingKernel = "CC";
    positionKnowledgeSrc = "R";
    attitudeKnowledgeSrc = "R";
    revNumber = 11444;
END_GROUP = IMAGE_1 
END;

Comment: Why can't you define the extent with `extent(g)=extent(raster(xmn=...xmx=...,ymn=...,ymx=...))` with the correct extent boundaries?

Comment: What does command-line `gdalinfo` tell you about the tif? Are there any other metadata files with it?

Comment: I can't run gdalinfo becasue I do not have GDAL installed and cannot install it on this work computer. When I try to add the extents it gives this error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extent’ for signature ‘"missing"’

Comment: There are several associated files that arcmap might be using, including: .RPB, .IMD, .GEO, .EPH, and .ATT

Comment: `r=raster() ; extent(r)=extent(raster(xmn=1,xmx=2,ymn=1,ymx=2))` should work to reassign an extent. Note the construction of a raster *within* the `extent` call. Otherwise you get that "missing" error.

Answer (score 1):

This suggests that this is not a good geotiff file. But you can fix it, as pointed out by Spacedman, with `extent`. I would do:

```
g <- raster('16SEP22191919-M1BS-057310833010_01_P001.tif' )
extent(g) <- extent(-120.893178348, -120.703696534, 47.7366916019, 47.797656863)
```

(Note that you cannot name the arguments), unless you would do

```
 extent(g) <- extent(x=c(-120.893178348, -120.703696534, 47.7366916019, 47.797656863))
```

Also, you are not getting an error, you are getting a warning. It should still plot.

I think you do have GDAL installed via `rgdal`. For GDALinfo you can do:

```
library(rgdal)
GDALinfo('16SEP22191919-M1BS-057310833010_01_P001.tif' )
```

**Edit**

Reading the imd file is something gdal should do, but apparently does not, at least not in current rgdal. To work around it, this works for the file you supplied:

```
x <- readLines('test.imd')
y <- data.frame(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(x[grep("ULLon", x)[1]], ";")), "="), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(y) <- trim(y[1,])
y <- y[-1,]
ext <- extent(as.numeric(c(y$ULLon, y$LRLon, y$LRLat, y$ULLat)))

extent(g) <- ext
```

Comment: GDALinfo did work. This is what my Tiff shows:rows        4336   
columns     10651   
bands       8   
lower left origin.x        0   
lower left origin.y        0   
res.x       1   
res.y       1   
ysign       -1   
oblique.x   0   
oblique.y   0   
driver      GTiff   
projection  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

Comment: right, the file is not georeferenced

Comment: So, is ArcMap using a different metafile to correctly import it?

Comment: Perhaps there is a  ".tfw"  file ("world file")  that ArcGIS uses?

Comment: I suspect the  .imd file might be the culprit (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/what-is-a-raster-type.htm) - can you view its contents and maybe edit them into your question?

Comment: I have posted the contents of the .IMD file. Does raster or any other package access that information when importing a .tif? I assume this information is used by ArcMap and that is why it imports correctly.

Comment: Yes, that must be what is happening. I may build in support in raster, but I think this is something gdal should and can handle, but that is currently not  done via rgdal